# Why is array splice applied to array that splice is not directly applied to?

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I run this code:

```
var uniqueOccurrences = function (arr) {
    let occurrences = [];
    let arr1 = arr;

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let counter = 0;

        for (let j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
            if (arr[i] === arr1[j]) {
                counter++

                arr1.splice(j, 1);

                j--;

                console.log('i: ' + i + ' :: ' + 'j: ' + j + ':: arr: ' + arr + ' :: ' + 'arr1: ' + arr1);
            }
        }

        occurrences.push(counter);
    }
};

uniqueOccurrences([1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3]);
```

I get the following output:

```
i: 0 :: j: -1:: arr: 2,2,1,1,3 :: arr1: 2,2,1,1,3

i: 0 :: j: -1:: arr: 2,1,1,3 :: arr1: 2,1,1,3

i: 0 :: j: -1:: arr: 1,1,3 :: arr1: 1,1,3

i: 0 :: j: -1:: arr: 1,3 :: arr1: 1,3

i: 0 :: j: -1:: arr: 3 :: arr1: 3

i: 0 :: j: -1:: arr:  :: arr1:
```

I am quite confused because in my code I only apply array `splice` to `arr1`, yet both `arr` and `arr1` shrink. I see no reason for why `arr` should shrink given there are no operations on it the code. Could anyone explain why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: Slice and splice (notice the p) are two different functions, but I think you mistake them in your question. Please, correct it.

Comment: `arr` and `arr1` reference the same object. Changes to the object will be visible through both references.

Comment: Fixed and thanks @ Thomas Sablik, forgot it works that way in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

`arr` and `arr1` reference the same object. Changes to the object will be visible through both references.

Answer (score 0):

The `arr` is altered when `arr1` is altered, because Arrays are passed as references, not as values.

You can use `let arr1 = arr.slice()` or `let arr1 = [...arr]`.

Comment: _"Arrays are passed as references, not as values?"_ That's unrelated to arrays. Every variable is a reference to an object. Even in `let a = 2` the variable `a` is a reference to an immutable number object with value `2`.

Comment: @ThomasSablik, how do you mean? Integers, booleans and even strings (in JS) are assigned as values with `a = b` assignment. If you `let b = a`, b's value is not affected with further changes made on `a`. Or did I miss a point?

Comment: AFAIK they aren't. `let a = 2; let b = a;` is the same case. `a` and `b` are two variables pointing to the same object. You can't change `b` through `a` because integers, booleans and strings are immutable. An assignment will always change the reference. The only way to change `a` is an assignment.

Comment: @ThomasSablik, I see and I stand corrected. Feel free to correct my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

`let arr1 = arr` doesn't copy `arr`. It copies the `arr` reference, so after assignment both variables point to same array. That's why log shows changes in both.

To prevent it you could copy array. Shallow copy (creates new array with values from the old one):
`let a1 = [...a]`
or deep copy (shares no common value with old array), for which you might want to use some lib.